# Share Maven run configurations with other developers using Intellij IDEA

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, versioning, collaboration

We have the following project setup: Maven, Eclipse, Subversion. [Eclipse Launch configurations](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/run-debug/ref-launch_configurations.htm) are in a separate `docs` folder next to the `pom.xml`. The launch configurations run something like `mvn clean install -Pdev` or `mvn tomee:run -pl something-ear`

The good thing is that a shared run configuration is picked up by the IDE and shown in the *External Tools* run commands. This way, every developer that checks out this project immediately has access to run the build.

We would like to have something similar using IntelliJ IDEA, but I haven't found a good equivalent. What I have considered so far:

**Share run scripts**

My first idea was to replace the launch configurations with run scripts. I just could not figure out how to have those run scripts run inside IntelliJ IDEA just the way a Maven goal would be executed.

**Share IDEA project configuration**

The IDEA project configuration (specifically `.idea/runConfigurations`) inside the checked out directory is not a good solution. We have (speaking one IDEA project with different IDEA modules depending on the task at hand: as a developer you might need multiple IDEA modules (and sub-modules) in the same IDEA project

An IDEA project consisting of the following modules is not something unusal

```
projectA/trunk
projectB/tags/1.2
projectC/branches/some-change
```

---

My preferred solution would remove all IDE-specific configuration from the repository and have some kind of run definitions either in the project folder or a folder next to the pom.xml that a developer can run from the command line or from her IDE of choice.

The optimal solution would let me define something like this in the pom:

```
<runConfigs>
    <default>clean install</default>
    <container>tomee:run -pl something-ear</container>
</runConfigs>
```

This configuration would then be picked up by the IDE and provided as a run or launch configuration to the developer.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My current approach is a hybrid solution:

- No configuration in the separate modules
- One IDEA project configuration with run configurations managed in VCS

The `.idea/runConfigurations` directory is versioned separately from the project sources. It contains commands with a working directory set relative to the `PROJECT_DIR`:

```
<MavenRunnerParameters>
    …
    <option name="workingDirPath" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/path/to/submodule" />
</MavenRunnerParameters>
```

When setting up a new project, the developer also checks out this folder and has a set of pre-configured launch configurations for all projects. The downsides are

- All launch configurations are managed centrally instead of with the module
- The IDEA project directory has a fixed location relative to the modules. If you set up another project, you will have to change the run configurations
- The setup does not clearly state how changes to the launch configurations are shared with other developers